# Char 2d Array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am using following definition in a function:

```
int FindInMatrix(char *matrix[MAXROW][MAXCOL],char* s);
```

Now to call this function , i have created an array like this:

```
char *charArr[5][5];
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
 {
   *charArr[i][0] = 't';
   *charArr[i][1] = 'e';
   *charArr[i][2] = 'a';
   *charArr[i][3] = 'm';
   *charArr[i][4] = 's';
 }
}

char *findS="team";
int res=0; 
res=FindInMatrix(&c, findS);
```

**But it is giving me a segmentation fault error. Can you please explain me what does 'char *matrix[][]' mean and how do I initialize an array to pass into this function call as a parameter?**

Comment: Ultimately you have no memory backing all those indeterminate pointers in your array. You have 25 pointers to the unknown, and as such any dereference (or even eval) is invoking *undefined behavior*. I think you're using the wrong data construct. It appears you want an array of 5 pointers to strings, each of which is 5 char elements.

Comment: `what does 'char *matrix[][]' mean `  It's a 5x5 array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: Is `SearchWord` and `FindInMatrix` to be considered the same?

Comment: Yes. SearchWord and FindInMatrix are same... Typo error (Now edited)

Answer (score 0):

Call like this:

```
SearchWord(charArr, findS);
```

charArr is already a pointer to two dimensional array:

```
char *charArr[5][5];
```

So, charArr will work properly.

Note: I suggest you to use your code like below (it's simpler and easier to read/understand):

```
int FindInMatrix(char matrix[MAXROW][MAXCOL], char* s);

char charArr[5][5];

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    charArr[i][0] = 't';
    charArr[i][1] = 'e';
    charArr[i][2] = 'a';
    charArr[i][3] = 'm';
    charArr[i][4] = 's';
}

char *findS = "team";
int res = 0; 
res = SearchWord( c, findS );
```

Comment: If you do this, then be careful that `SearchWord` (and/or `FindInMatrix`) does not treat `matrix` as if it contains a string, which it doesn't because there is no null-termination.

Comment: I had this question in some test and therefore i cannot change the signature of the function. It'll remain as char * matrix[][]. Any other suggestions